# @ManagedProperty in a javax.annotation.ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, javabeans, facelets

I'm able to use ManagedProperty when using the faces version of ManagedBean, but not when its a `javax.annotation.ManagedBean`

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TripListProducer {
   @Inject
   private TripDao tripDao;

   private List<Trip> trips_list;

   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.active}")
   private Boolean active = true;
```

I'm using the `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` because that is the only way I was able to use `@Produces` and `@Named` with `<h:dataTable var="_trip" value="#{trips}"` in my facelet. I kind of like that better in the facelet as opposed to `<h:dataTable var="_trip" value="#{tripListProducer.trip.trip_list}"` if using the faces version of ManagedBean.

```
@Produces
@Named
public List<Trip> getTrips() {
   return trips_list;
}
```

And the reason I was trying to use `@ManagedProperty` because I want the user to be able to choose to display list of active only trips or all trips. I prefer to be using RESTful urls `.com/SkiClub/trips/active` or `.com/SkiClub/index.xhtml?active=false`

```
@PostConstruct
public void retrieveAllTripsOrderedByDate() {
   System.out.println("Active Only? " + active);
  if (active) {
        trips_list = tripDao.findAllActiveOrderedByStartDate();         
     } else {
        trips_list = tripDao.findAllOrderedByStartDate();
     }
  }
```

But active always stays to the default true.  Not to tack on too much in my question, but I also feel that the if statement in my retrieveAllTripsOrderedByDate may not be the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide between jsf managed beans and (cdi) javabeans. Can't mix both annotation types in one bean.

For your @ManagedProperty use there's [omnifaces' @Param](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Param) annotation, so you can go full CDI.

Comment: I just got back to the office from the holidays.  Today, I'll look into using primefaces as you suggest and report back. thanks.

Comment: That'd be OmniFaces, I added a link. Note that `@Param` covers the case you describe (accessing request parameters), it's not a complete replacement.